# Converting blob from database to an image javascript

Tags: node.js, database, reactjs, blob

I have a database, where one of the tables has a blob field and I want to display it as an image. I can't really find any solution for this - any working npm package or a sample of code would be useful. I'm using reactjs and nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is create an URL that you can pass to the img src of the HTML img

JS

```
var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var imageSrc = url.createObjectURL('your blob');
document.querySelector("#myimage").src = imageSrc;
```

HTML

```
<img id="myimage"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 create readable stream and pipe to response

```
var stream = require('stream');
var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
bufferStream.end(new Buffer( blob, 'binary' ));
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type' : 'image/jpg'
});
// res is standered express res object
bufferStream.pipe(res)
```

Method 2 
pass blob to base64

```
var bufferBase64 = new Buffer( blob, 'binary' ).toString('base64');
```

show image

```
class Example extends React.Component{

    render() {
        return <img src={"data:image/jpeg;" + bufferBase64} />
    }
}
```

reference 
https://stackoverflow.com/.../how-to-create-a-readstream-with-a-buffer-using-nodejs

Comment: I'm fighting with it for a while now (method 2), but the conversion itself is not working - I even console logged bufferBase64 and pasted it as a string into the image's src and it won't return a working image. Do you maybe know the reason why?

Comment: The problem was with the blob file, which was in my database. Eventually I used different code, but the one you sent here would probably work as well